# Saving form data to DB and sending it to an API; Django

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to capture user information. Upon submitting the form, the data is saved to a DB. I'd also like to send the zipcode field to the sunlight foundation's API to provide users with helpful information once the form is submitted.

When the sunlight script is in HOME.HTML, it returns a list based on the zipcode, but the data isn't saved by Django. When the script is removed from HOME.HTML, the data is saved to the database. How can I have the best of both worlds, where, the data is saved by Django and the list is rendered after the user submits the form. Should I be placing the sunlight script somewhere else (views.py?)?

Thanks for taking the time to look this over and potentially help!

***HOME.HTML***

```
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

        Join our cause:

        <form action="" id="rep-lookup" method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}

                {{form.as_p}}

            <input type="submit" id="btn-lookup" class="btn" value="Join" />
        </form>

        <div id="rep-lookup-results">
        </div>

    </div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script>
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rep-lookup').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $results = $('#rep-lookup-results'),
            zipcode = $('#id_zipcode').val(),
            apiKey = 'xxx';

        var requestURL = 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?callback=?';

        // collect the data

        $.getJSON(requestURL, {
            'apikey' : apiKey,
            'zip' : zipcode,
        }, function(data){
            if (data.results && data.results.length > 0) {

                var mySenators = '<p>Here are your reps.<br> Please urge them to support the cause.</p>';

                $.each(data.results, function(i, rep) {
                        mySenators += '<p>';
                        mySenators += '<a href="' + rep.contact_form + '" target="_blank" class="repname">';
                        mySenators += '</a> ';
                        mySenators += rep.state + '</span><br>';
                        mySenators += '</p><hr>';
                });

                $results.html(mySenators);
            } else {
                $results.html('<p style="color:#ff0000;">No reps found for this zip code:' + zipcode + '.<br>Please try again...</p>');
            }
        });

    });
});


</script>
```

***FORMS.PY***

```
from django import forms 
from .models import SignUp 

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SignUp
        fields = ['name_last', 'name_first', 'email', 'zipcode',]

#overriding/adding to django validation
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        return email

    def clean_name_first(self):
        name_first = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        #write validation code.
        return name_first

    def clean_zipcode(self):
        zipcode = self.cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
        return zipcode
```

***MODELS.PY***

```
from django.db import models

class SignUp(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120)
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True) #optional and also: default=''
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=120,)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=120,)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.email
```

***VIEWS.PY***

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import SignUpForm

def home(request):
    title = 'Welcome'
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None) 

    context = {
        "title": title,
        "form": form,
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        if not first_name:
            first_name = "None Given"
            instance.first_name = first_name
        instance.save()
        context = {
        "title": "Thanks",
        }   

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about calling sunlight's API from inside the view. This can be done as follows:

```
    def home(request):
        if request.method=="POST":
            payload = {'apikey' : apiKey,
                    'zip' : request.POST.get('zipcode'),}
            response = requests.get("http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?callback=?",params=payload)
```

Now use this response as you wish. Process the response as you did in the template and pass the processed data in context back.

You need not hit the API via js. In your template just submit the form.